# useState of props undefined in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, use-state

I'm trying to give a value of the props `note` to the `TextField` but if I use `TextInput` the result is undefined and if I use the `note` props, I cannot change the value of the `TextField` afterward.
When I console log both of the value, they render twice as shown in the image.
I tried useEffect also to set the state.

```
export default function ProfileNote({ contact }) {
  const { note, id } = contact;
  const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState(note);
  
  console.log(`textInput:  ${textInput}`)
  console.log(`note:  ${note}`)  

  const handleTextInputChange = event => {
    setTextInput(event.target.value);
  };

return (
    <FormProvider onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
       <TextField
         name="notes"
         label="Notes"
         onChange={handleTextInputChange}
         value={textInput}
       />
    </FormProvider>
  );
}
```

Image of the console.log

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the code that calls `ProfileNote` receives the `contact` asynchronously from a database or an API. When the asynchronous call is started, the value of `contact.note` is still undefined, but your component is still rendered.

This undefined value is now used as the initial value for `textField`. Once the asynchronous function call returns with a value (e.g. `ddfdf`), the `textField` value will not be changed since it is already initialized.

You can do one of two things in order to fix this, dependent on how you want your UI to behave:

- prevent rendering the `ProfileNote` until the data is available:

```js
<>
{ contact != null && <ProfileNote contact={contact}/> }
</>
```

- continuously apply changes to `contact.note` to `textField`, potentially overwriting user input if `contact` changes while the user is editing:

```js
useEffect(() => setTextInput(note), [note]);
```

Comment: or ussually we use `{ contact && <ProfileNote contact={contact}/> }`

Comment: Don't know if you meant useEffect(() => setTextInput(note), [note]); but that worked perfectly! Thanks

Comment: Yes, I changed it to setTextInput now